# How do I get my vector to display 8 integers after entering them? When I do enter 8 integers, it only displays zeros and not what I entered

Tags: c++, vector, output

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int val = 8;
    vector<int>numVal(val);
    unsigned int i;

    cout << "Enter " << val << " integers: "<< endl;
    for(i = 0; i < numVal.size(); i++) 
    {
        cin >> val;
    }

   cout << "Congratulations! You entered 8 integers." << endl;

   for(i = 0; i < numVal.size(); i++)
   {
       cout << numVal.at(i)<<" ";
   }  

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would help if you stored the integers in the vector.

Comment: Do you expect `cin >> val;` to make any changes to `numVal`?

Comment: `vector<int>numVal(val);` stores `val` many zeroes in the vector. You probably want `vector<int>numVal; numVal.reserve(val);`

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow If they wanted to do `cin >> temp; numVal.push_back(temp);`, yes. Their current approach is actually pretty close to working with fewer changes; just `cin >> numVal[i];` instead of `cin >> val;`

Comment: @NathanPierson that's where the *probably* comes from. I would consider it slightly wasteful. Which make me think: can you write `numVal.emplace_back_from_ostream(cin)` in some way already?

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing the `vector` with 8 default-valued elements, and then you are ignoring the user's input completely. That is why you are printing zeros.

You need to store the user's input in the `vector`, either by:

- using the `vector`'s  `operator[]` to access the pre-allocated elements:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> numVal(8);
    size_t i;

    cout << "Enter " << numVal.size() << " integers: "<< endl;
    for(i = 0; i < numVal.size(); i++) 
    {
        cin >> numVal[i];
    }

   cout << "Congratulations! You entered " << numVal.size() << " integers." << endl;

   for(i = 0; i < numVal.size(); i++)
   {
       cout << numVal[i] << " ";
   }  

   return 0;
}
```

- not pre-filling the `vector`'s elements, but using its `push_back()` method instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int val;
    vector<int> numVal;
    size_t i;

    numVal.reserve(8);

    cout << "Enter " << numVal.capacity() << " integers: "<< endl;
    for(i = 0; i < numVal.capacity(); i++) 
    {
        cin >> val;
        numVal.push_back(val);
    }

   cout << "Congratulations! You entered " << numVal.size() << " integers." << endl;

   for(i = 0; i < numVal.size(); i++)
   {
       cout << numVal[i] << " ";
   }  

   return 0;
}
```